# Yii and Bizrules in CDbAuthManager

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I'm really confused by Yii's bizrules and authitems in general. At the moment I'm getting stuck in how to implement the following. I've got multiple `Team` model instances, these have multiple `User` model instances assigned. Now I want to authorize multiple of those assigned users as `team admin` (`AuthItem`).

Storing it in `AuthAssignment` seems to be the most logical way to store it to me, since I simply want to assign a `AuthItem` to a user. I can also store data to the assignment, so I'll be able to store the team_id with the assignment as well. But this seems to be really inefficient in Yii, since (as far as I can tell) will have to store a bizrule to every single assignment like: `return $data['team_id'] === $params['team_id'];`.

Is there something I'm missing? Or should I just go and store the assignments outside `AuthAssignment` and store it in my custom table?

Answer (score 0):

You may use default roles as described in the guide:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth

```
return array(
    'components'=>array(
        'authManager'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
            'defaultRoles'=>array('team_admin'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now the `team_admin` role will be assigned to every user without assigning to everyone individually, however you can restrict it with a bizrule:

```
$bizRule="return {$data['team_id']} === {$params['team_id']};";
$auth->createRole('team_admin', 'Team admin', $bizRule);
```